# Cannot deploy Angular 8 app to Heroku using Bitbucket Pipeline

Tags: node.js, angular, heroku, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to deploy an Angular 8 app to Heroku, but it fails in the deploy process.

After research on internet, I've found that the `package.json` needs to be in the root folder of the project, and it is.

[image: project structure]

This is the error message I get everytime I try to deploy.

```
-----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/nodejs.tgz

 !     ERROR: Application not supported by 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack
 !     
 !     The 'heroku/nodejs' buildpack is set on this application, but was
 !     unable to detect a Node.js codebase.
 !         
 !     A Node.js app on Heroku requires a 'package.json' at the root of
 !     the directory structure.
 !     
 !     If you are trying to deploy a Node.js application, ensure that this
 !     file is present at the top level directory. This directory has the
 !     following files:
 !     
 !     assets/
 !     favicon.ico
 !     index-tst.html
 !     main-es2015.js
 !     main-es2015.js.map
 !     main-es5.js
 !     main-es5.js.map
 !     polyfills-es2015.js
 !     polyfills-es2015.js.map
 !     polyfills-es5.js
 !     polyfills-es5.js.map
 !     runtime-es2015.js
 !     runtime-es2015.js.map
 !     runtime-es5.js
 !     runtime-es5.js.map
 !     styles-es2015.js
 !     styles-es2015.js.map
 !     styles-es5.js
 !     styles-es5.js.map
 !     vendor-es2015.js
 !     vendor-es2015.js.map
 !     vendor-es5.js
 !     vendor-es5.js.map
 !         
 !     If you are trying to deploy an application written in another
 !     language, you need to change the list of buildpacks set on your
 !     Heroku app using the 'heroku buildpacks' command.
```

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
pipeline setup:

```
image: node:10.15.3

pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: 'Build app'
          caches:
            - node
          script:
            - npm install --quiet
            - npm run build-tst --progress=false
          artifacts:
            - dist/pa-bo/**
      - step:
          name: 'Create zip'
          script:
            - tar czfv application.tgz dist/pa-bo
          artifacts:
            - application.tgz
      - step:
          name: 'Deploy Backoffice to Heroku TST environment'
          deployment: tst
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/heroku-deploy:0.1.1
              variables:
                HEROKU_API_KEY: $HEROKU_API_KEY
                HEROKU_APP_NAME: $HEROKU_APP_NAME
                ZIP_FILE: "application.tgz"
                WAIT: 'true' # wait for build completion and exit the pipe
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Bitbucket pipeline but it looks like you are deploying the builded project to Heroku. Heroku however requires the source code to your project but it is receiving the builded files. Can you show how you have your Bitbucket pipeline set up?

Comment: @TinNguyen Original post edited.